# How does React affect CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was referencing a CSS file in my HTML using the standard `<link>` tag but now I've moved it so that it's applied in the Javascript like this...

```
import 'main.css'
```

Now things look subtly different. For example, the spacing is missing on some elements.

Are there some tips for making it look exactly as it did before?

Comment: Give specific examples. Post your CSS.

Comment: That's probably due to some styles was replaced by another in a different order. In case you using separate css files per component. If css is same - please post here a link to live example. Would be good two links on each approaches.

Comment: If you could explain the principle then that would apply to all examples. But nevermind, I will do some research.

Comment: It still didn't work when I moved my styles back to regular `<link>`s. I didn't mention that I was also migrating to a new React project and it was a `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the new `index.html` that was resulting in a different layout. I must not have HTML5 valid code.